# How to highlight the difference value in excel using python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two excel files stored in my local(Example:file1 and file2)
Both files might have different shape(file 1-[3][3], file2 -[4][3])
I need to compare both excel files and highlight the differences in file2

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
import xlwings as xw

# Read the source and target Excel files
file1_path = 'C:\\Users\\kckp959\\OneDrive - AZCollaboration\\Desktop\\Automation_Folder\\sourceFile.xlsx'
file2_path = 'C:\\Users\\kckp959\\OneDrive - AZCollaboration\\Desktop\\Automation_Folder\\TargetFile.xlsx'

df1 = pd.read_excel(file1_path)
df2 = pd.read_excel(file2_path)

# Merge DataFrames on all columns

#Final=df1.compare(df2, align_axis=1, keep_shape=False, keep_equal=False)
final= df1.compare(df2,keep_shape=True, keep_equal=False)

print(final)



Final_file=pd.DataFrame(final)

excel_file_path = "C:\\Users\\kckp959\OneDrive - AZCollaboration\\Desktop\\Automation_Folder\\finalfile.xlsx"
final.to_excel(excel_file_path)
print(f"Excel file created at: {excel_file_path}")
#print(differences_df)

# Open the workbook with openpyxl
wb = load_workbook("C:\\Users\\kckp959\OneDrive - AZCollaboration\\Desktop\\Automation_Folder\\finalfile.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

df2_highlighted = pd.DataFrame(index=df2.index, columns=df2.columns)
# Iterate through each cell and highlight differences
# Iterate through each cell and highlight differences
for i, row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=ws.max_row, min_col=1, max_col=ws.max_column)):
    for j, cell in enumerate(row):
        # Check if the cell contains any value indicating a difference
        if cell.value != 0:  # Assuming 0 is the default value for no difference
            df2_highlighted.iat[i, j] = f'Difference: {cell.value}'


# Save the highlighted df2 to a new sheet in the Excel file
df2_highlighted.to_excel(wb, sheet_name='df2_highlighted', index=False)



# Save the changes
wb.save("C:\\Users\\kckp959\OneDrive - AZCollaboration\\Desktop\\Automation_Folder\\finalfile.xlsx")
```

`

I tried to save the changes in new file and higlight the difference value

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

# Read the source and target Excel files
file1_path = 'C:\\Users\\kckp959\\OneDrive - AZCollaboration\\Desktop\\Automation_Folder\\sourceFile.xlsx'
file2_path = 'C:\\Users\\kckp959\\OneDrive - AZCollaboration\\Desktop\\Automation_Folder\\TargetFile.xlsx'

df1 = pd.read_excel(file1_path)
df2 = pd.read_excel(file2_path)

# Find differences between DataFrames
differences = df1.compare(df2, keep_shape=True, keep_equal=False)

# Open the workbook with openpyxl
wb = load_workbook("C:\\Users\\kckp959\\OneDrive - AZCollaboration\\Desktop\\Automation_Folder\\finalfile.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

# Create a new DataFrame for highlighted differences
df2_highlighted = df2.applymap(lambda x: f'Difference: {x}' if pd.notnull(x) else '')

# Write the highlighted differences to a new sheet
with pd.ExcelWriter("C:\\Users\\kckp959\\OneDrive - AZCollaboration\\Desktop\\Automation_Folder\\finalfile.xlsx", engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    writer.book = wb
    df2_highlighted.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='df2_highlighted', index=False)

    # Iterate through each cell and apply fill color to highlight differences
    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=ws.max_row, min_col=1, max_col=ws.max_column):
        for cell, difference_value in zip(row, differences.itertuples(index=False)):
            if difference_value != 0:
                cell.fill = PatternFill(start_color="FFFF00", end_color="FFFF00", fill_type="solid")

# Save the changes
wb.save("C:\\Users\\kckp959\\OneDrive - AZCollaboration\\Desktop\\Automation_Folder\\finalfile.xlsx")
```